# java-selenium xpath to find preceding node

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I have below code

```
<div>
<tr class="clickable-row" _ngcontent-c2="">
.
.
.
<tr class="clickable-row" _ngcontent-c2="">
   <td _ngcontent-c2="">
     <input type="checkbox" _ngcontent-c2="" value="">
   </td>
   <td _ngcontent-c2=""> 
      View only 
   </td>
</tr>
<div>
```

Now I want to click on the check box near the 'View only ' text. I tried

```
 //input[@type='checkbox']/following::td[contains(text(),'View only')]
```

but it clicks on the text not the check box. 
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Looks to me like it selects the `td` containing "View only". Also, this is nothing to do with Java or Selenium.

Answer (score 1):

To click on the *checkbox* near the *'View only'* text you can use the following *xpath* :

```
//tr[@type='clickable-row']//td[normalize-space()='View only']//preceding::td[1]/input[@type='checkbox']
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can traverse up in xpath by adding `..` to the part where you want to go up. To do so, you need to grab the child element *before* you go up.

I am assuming you want to click the checkbox that is one level above the 'View only' text, and that the text + checkbox combination is unique (there is no other 'View only' text with a checkbox above it in the same page); in that case the xpath you want is

```
//td[contains(text(), 'View only')]/../td/input`.
```

This xpath goes to the `td` that contains 'View only', goes up one level to the `tr`, then to the first `td` and to the input.

If you want a simpler match for the text you can do `td[normalize-space()='View only']`; if you want to be more specific after the `/../` and tell to grab the first `td` you can put `td[1]`, and you can also add the `[@type='checkbox']` to the input to ensure you grab the one that is a checkbox.